# How to get returned data from buttons

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```py
### This is a class for making buttons
import discord

class SelectionButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 60):
        super().__init__(timeout = timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label = '1', style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def button1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return 1
    @discord.ui.button(label = '<', style = discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def buttonback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return '<'
```

In another file, I call that class with the following script

```py
view = SelectionButtons()
user_response = await context.send(embed = embed, view = view)


if user_response == 1:
    print('1')
elif user_response == '<':
    print('<')
```

How do I get the response from user if he reacted on the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a variable to the user's input and then access it with with the `view` in your other file.

```
class SelectionButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 60):
        super().__init__(timeout = timeout)
        self.choice = None

    @discord.ui.button(label = '1', style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def button1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.choice = "1"
        # self.stop() would go here
    @discord.ui.button(label = '<', style = discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def buttonback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.choice = "<"
        # self.stop() would go here
```

```
view = SelectionButtons()
await context.send(embed = embed, view = view)

# Wait statement goes here

print(view.choice)
```

Note that it will print `None` at first.
You can either wait until your view is finished with `await view.wait()` (Call `self.stop()` at the end of the button functions to have the view finish right after clicking a button), or check after a certain time with `await asyncio.sleep()` or check in a while loop. Choose what works best for you.